# How to clean up state post lambda time out

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We use APIG and Lambda to process long running jobs. These jobs have an id which needs to unique. In order to capture duplicate job submissions /createJob Lambda checks an job exists (if not adds an entry into db) and requests to schedule that job.

We had an issue where an entry was made into db but before the request could be sent the lambda (Which executes /createJob) terminated. We believe it was due some network latency.

Though its an rare event, wanted to check that are available mechanisms for rollback (i.e. delete that entry from db in case the lambda fails to execute)

Comment: I believe we need mechanism through which lambda failure triggers another lambda that could clean up ?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have not shared the lambda code, I think it is better to commit to the DB *after* the major steps in lambda are completed rather than *before* everything else. This way, if there is a failure for some reason, there will be no entry made to the DB and you don't need to rollback anything.

Comment: The reason for DB commit ahead was to avoid duplicate job executions. Which happens for often that the case in question